# A Banach space that satisfies this condition is a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $X$ a Banach space that satisfies:

If $\varepsilon\in(0,2)$, $x,y\in X$ with norm equal to $1$ and $||x-y||\geq\varepsilon$ then $||x+y||^2\leq 2||x||^2+2||y||^2-\varepsilon^2$. I'm trying to prove that $X$ is a Hilbert space.

My attempt and intuiton is that I must get with this condition the parallelogram identity, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for any suggestion or help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible that you are asked to prove the result from a stronger hypothesis?  I note for example that your hypothesis on $X$ refers to a condition involving $\|x\|^2$ and $\|y\|^2$, when $\|x\|$ and $\|y\|$ are already assumed to be $1$.  It's not clear why the hypothesis on $X$ would refer to $\|x\|^2$ and $\|y\|^2$ by those names when both of those things are known to be $1$.

Anyway, I don't immediately see an elementary way of proving this result (in a similar vein, I don't know of a super-simple proof that a Banach space satisfying parallelogram identity is a Hilbert space), but if you'll allow some citation to publicly available papers, I can sketch an argument why the result is true.

For $\epsilon \in (0,2]$ define
$$
\delta_X(\epsilon) = \inf \left\{1 - \frac{\|x+y\|}{2} : x \in X, y \in X, \|x\| = 1, \|y\| = 1, \|x - y\| \geq \epsilon\right\}.
$$
Side note:

> This function is sometimes known as the modulus of convexity of the Banach space $X$.  I am not sure if the notion originated in James Clarkson's paper [Uniformly Convex Spaces, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 40 (1936), 396-414](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1936-1501880-4) (free download) but I first learned of it there; since that paper, it is an invariant that has been well studied for various spaces by many authors.  Clarkson computes $\delta$ for Hilbert spaces and analyzes $\delta$ for spaces including $L^p$ spaces; Olof Hanner in [On the uniform convexity of Lp and lp, Ark. Mat. 3(3): 239-244 (22 Febr. 1956)](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02589410) (free download) gives an explicit formula for $\delta$ for all $L^p$ spaces, $1 < p < \infty$.

Fix $\epsilon \in (0,2)$.  For any $x,y \in X$ with $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$ and $\|x - y\| \geq \epsilon$, your hypothesis on $X$ implies that $\|x+y\|^2 \leq 2(1)^2 + 2(1^2) - \epsilon^2 = 4 - \epsilon^2$, which implies that $\|x+y\| \leq \sqrt{4 - \epsilon^2}$, which implies that $1 - \frac{\|x+y\|}{2} \geq 1 - \sqrt{1 - (\epsilon/2)^2}$.  We then deduce from the definition of $\delta_X$ that
$$
\delta_X(\epsilon) \geq 1 - \sqrt{1 - (\epsilon/2)^2}, \qquad \epsilon \in (0,2).
$$
Since the triangle inequality implies that $\delta_X(\epsilon) \geq 0$ for all $\epsilon \in (0,2]$ and $1-\sqrt{1 - (2/2)^2} = 0$, we even have the inequality just written for $\epsilon = 2$.  The desired result - that $X$ is a Hilbert space - then follows from Theorem 4.1 of Mahlon Day's [Some Characterizations of Inner-Product Spaces, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 62 (1947), 320-337](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1947-0022312-9) (free download) (as Day observes around that result, the right hand side of the above $1 - \sqrt{1 - (\epsilon/2)^2}$ is the modulus of convexity of an inner product space).

In connection with my questions that began this sketch of an answer, I note that a preliminary - and to my mind nontrivial - result in Day's paper is the fact that a normed space is an inner-product space if and only if the parallelogram identity is assumed to hold for only for all pairs of *unit* vectors (see his Theorem 2.1).  So if the hypothesis on $X$ in your problem could be strengthened to involve pairs of vectors that were not all assumed to have unit length, maybe some of the issues dealt with in Day's paper, or perhaps any use of Day's paper, could be avoided.