# No inner product for $L^p$-spaces with $p \in [1,\infty]\setminus\{2\}$

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, inner-products

Consider $(X, A, \mu)$ as a measure space where $A$ contains at least two disjoint sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ with positive, finite measures. Let $p$ be in the interval $[1, \infty]\setminus\{2\}$. The goal is to show that there does not exist an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : L^p(X) \times L^p(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that induces the $L^p$-norm, i.e., $\|f\|_{L^p} = \sqrt{\langle f, f \rangle}$ for all $f \in L^p(X)$.

I want to show this by using a proof of contradiction and without using the parallelogramm law. Since we know that we have at least two disjoint sets with positive finite measures, I want to define a function $f$ which takes the value $1$ on $A_1$ and $A_2$ and $0$ elsewhere. Therefore we get

$$\|f\|_{L^p} = \biggl(\int_{X}f^pd\mu\biggr)^\frac{1}{p} = \biggl(\int_{A_1 \cup A_2}1d\mu\biggr)^\frac{1}{p} = (m(A_1) + m(A_2))^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

where $m(A_1)$ and $m(A_2)$ denote the (finite, positive) measure of $A_1$ and $A_2$ respectively. This ultimately gives us

$$\langle f, f \rangle = \|f\|_{L^p}^{2} = (m(A_1) + m(A_2))^{\frac{2}{p}}$$

But unfortunately, I am a little stuck here. I would somehow like to show that we have $\langle f, f \rangle = (m(A_1) + m(A_2))$ so that we can nicely see that $p$ has to be $2$ in order for that to be true.

Or is there any other approach I should rather consider for this specific example? I think I necessarily need to include the two disjoint sets $A_1, A_2$ with finite, positive measure in my proof which is why I came up with the approach above. But I am open for any suggestions.

Comment: I suppose you may be interested in these: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4520721/a-banach-space-that-satisfies-this-condition-is-a-hilbert-space

Comment: By the way, set difference is denoted by $\setminus$, not $/$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(a,b) \to a\mu(A_1)^{-1/p}1_{A_1}+b\mu(A_2)^{-1/p}1_{A_2}$ is an isomtric isomorphism from $\mathbb R^{2}$ with the $p-$ norm into $L^{p}(X)$. Since $\mathbb R^{2}$ with the $p-$ norm has no inner product, $L^{p}(X)$ cannot have one either.

[Parallelogram Law holds in $\mathbb R^{2}$ with the $p-$ norm only for $p=2$].

Comment: I really like this argument! However, we didn't show in the course that $\mathbb{R}^2$ has no inner product with the $p$-norm and at first glance that doesn't seem that trivial to me (even though the parallelogram law provides a pretty easy argument even though I try to avoid using it in this proof). What bothers me a little bit is the condition that we need $\textit{at least}$ two disjoint sets with finite positive measure. Why two and not just one?

Comment: If there is only one set of positive mesaure (which has to be the whole space)  then $L^{p}(X)$ is one -dimensional, all norms on it are constant multiples of each other so any norm is given by an inner product. @MathGeek